# Hide/Show HTML elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my JS:

```
function showReturning(){
    document.getElementById("returningdate").style.display = 'block';
```

}

And this is my HTML:

```
        <input type="radio" name="triptype" value="roundtrip" onclick="showReturning()"/><label>Round Trip</label>

        <td class="hiddenReturning">
        <label>Returning:</label>
        <input type="text" name="returningdate" id="returningdate" required="required" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
        </td>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.hiddenReturning{
    display:none;
}
```

When I click the radio button, the text box is not being displayed.

Comment: If a tag's parent is hidden, even if the tag itself has display:block it will still be hidden. You need to unhide the parent tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

The textbox is not hidden, it's the td that wraps it.
Either change the textbox only to be hidden or change the td's style.

This will hide the textbox:

```
   <td>
        <label>Returning:</label>
        <input class="hiddenReturning" type="text" name="returningdate" id="returningdate" required="required" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is working now. try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #returningdate
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="radio" id="radio" />Click<br />

        <td class="hiddenReturning">
            <label>Returning:</label>
            <input type="text" name="returningdate" id="returningdate" />
        </td>

        <script>
            var getback = document.getElementById('returningdate');
            function showReturning()
            {
                getback.style.display = 'block';
            }

            var radio = document.getElementById('radio');

            radio.addEventListener('change', showReturning, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/g92ps/

Comment: hi friends .. why are you add LINK tag ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> why add style.css

Comment: sorry, you can ignore that, there is nothing in that file, the css is on the page itself, is the answer according to what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try This :

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="triptype" value="roundtrip" onclick="showReturning()"/><label>Round Trip</label>

    <td class="hiddenReturning" id="new_id">
    <label>Returning:</label>
    <input type="text" name="returningdate" id="returningdate" required="required" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
    </td>
```

**JS**

```
function showReturning()
{
document.getElementById("new_id").style.display = 'block';
}
```

**CSS**

```
#new_id{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as follows :

```
<style type="text/css">
 #returningdate{
  display:none;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="id" />
```

for show and hide

using javascript

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("id").style.display="none";
```

using css

```
#id{
    display:block;
    display:none;
    }
```

using jQuery

```
$('#id').show();
$('#id').hide();
```